# How to let Jenkins create a temp directory?

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way/configuration to let jenkins create a temporary directory where to store files created by an application? At the end this temporary directory should be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with *Add Build Step* > *Execute Shell*. There you simply create the folder and also remove it at the end.

If the folder can be located within the Job's workspace, the [workspace cleanup plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin) might be of help as it allows you to delete the workspace once the build is completed.